# KeyValuePair deconstruction in ToDictionary

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Can I deconstruct `KeyValuePair` as lambda argument in `ToDictionary` method like it could be done in `foreach`?
So, is there any possibility to write something like this:

```cs
dict.ToDictionary((key, value) => key, (key, value) => 2*value);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you have to write it like this:

```
var d = dict.ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Value * 2);
```